# Recreating histogram ldahist() in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm trying to recreate the histogram that is returned when plot(LDA) function from MASS is called in ggplot:

```
ld1<-lda(Species ~., iris)

plot(ld1, type = "histogram", dimen = 1)
```

[image]

I think I have cracked the x axis by doing the following:

```
iris.scaled<- cbind(scale(as.matrix(iris[,-5]),scale=FALSE) %*% 
irisLda$scaling,iris[,5,drop=FALSE])
```

As when I plot this I get this:

```
ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x=LD1),data=iris.scaled)
```

However, I'm still unsure as how to get the y-axis. Currently it is a count, but I'm guessing I need to covert it to a percentage representation by bin or something like that. Could someone tell me what I need to extract from the lda object and how I can used it in the ggplot2 call please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main adjustment needed was to the y-aesthetic. Changing from the default "count" to "density".

Also I defined the number of bins to approximate what `plot()` was providing (~20), `geom_histogram()` defaults to 30. The last step is faceting by `Species`.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = LD1, y = stat(density)), bins = 20, data = iris.scaled) +
  facet_grid(Species ~ .)
```

[image]

Comment: Cool thanks! seems to work fine. I tried to look at the function but was quite complicated. Cheers.